# facebook login issue with codiegniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-login

After login with Facebook this error message show, how to fix it?

this is my index function

```
    if($this->facebook->is_authenticated())

    {
    $data['user'] = array();
        $user = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,name,email');
        if (!isset($user['error']))
        {
            $data['user'] = $user;
        }
        $this->load->view('home',$data);


    }
    else{
    $data['user'] = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,name,email');
    $this->load->view('signin',$data);
}
```

Array ( [error] => 0 [message] => You must provide an access token. )

Comment: Refer this URL https://www.codexworld.com/facebook-login-codeigniter/

Comment: sir , every thing is right , but unable to  user authentication,every time run else part

Comment: Please check the user is already exist in DB or not?

Comment: no sir, user not exist

Comment: Try with this one https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-facebook-oauth/

Comment: now this return 0 $user = $this->facebook->getUser();